# Angularjs ajax call to postgresql not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, ajax, postgresql

I am new to angularjs,i could not able to store the details in database.In browser it is showing the output as saved successfully, but in PostgreSQL, it is not saving the data. I struck here from two days, can anyone help me with this code. 
I think the problem is mainly with the Ajax call to database. Here is the part of code. I tried all possibilities but could not able to reach. What is the Solution for this.

```
        > **Default.aspx**

             <div data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="myCntrl">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Student ID :
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="number" id="noStudentID" data-ng-model="studetnNo" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Student Name :
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" id="txtStudentName" data-ng-model="studetnName" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" data-align="center">
                                <input type="button" value="Save" data-ng-click="Save()" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
         <script>
                 var app = angular.module("myApp",[])
    app.controller("myCntrl",function($scope,$http)
    {
        $scope.studetnNo="";
        $scope.studetnName="";
        $scope.Save = function () {
            var httpreq = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'Default.aspx/Save',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    'dataType': 'json'
                },
                data: {
                    StudentID: $scope.studetnNo,
                    StudentName: $scope.studetnName
                }
            };
            $http(httpreq).success(function (response) {
                $scope.fillList();
                alert("Saved Succefully");
            });

        };
     });
    </script>

    > Default.aspx.cs
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
        public static void Save(int StudentID,string StudentName)
        {
            using (NpgsqlConnection con = new NpgsqlConnection(@"Server=10.0.5.22;Port=5432;Database=TEST_DB;User Id=postgres;Password=test;"))
            {
                using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.CommandText = "insert into student1(StudentID,StudentName)values(@StudentID,@StudentName);"; //DB table name and columns are correct
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentID", StudentID);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentName", StudentName);
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Replace ; with , on the line 'Content-Type':'application/json;

Comment: after replacing with "," also not working.

Comment: Which version  of angularjs are you using?

Comment: i am using version  1.6.5.

Comment: Success is deprecated in angular version of  1.6.x. Use .then instead

Answer (score 0):

You had incorrect syntax in the angular script (missing a '}'). Try this:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",[])
app.controller("myCntrl", function($scope,$http)
{    
    $scope.studetnNo = "";
    $scope.studetnName = "";

    $scope.Save = function()
    {
        var httpreq = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'Default.aspx/Save',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                'dataType': 'json'
            },
            data: {
                StudentID: $scope.studetnNo,
                StudentName: $scope.studetnName
            }
        };
        $http(httpreq).success(function(response)
        {
            $scope.fillList();
            alert("Saved Succefully");
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Can your try calling your http endpoint with a program like [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) first? Just to make sure http://host:port/Default.aspx/Save which you are calling is correct.